# when i change parameter name from page to id its work other wise not work in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

my problem is that while i am pass query string controller method accepting query string value . while i am passing value as as route it was not accepting value and showing null value  . when i convert parameter name page to id then it show value is accepting route value

**Route**

```
  routes.MapRoute("videoCategory", // route name 
            "{Controller}/{action}/{page}",
            defaults : new 
            { Controller = "Category", Action = "Videos", Page = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

**controller**
when i change parameter name from page to id its work

```
 public ActionResult Videos(string page  )
    {
        List<Videos> vid = new List<Videos>();
        vid = modelvid.getVideos(page);
        ViewBag.Pagecount = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)modelvid.VideosCount(page) / (double)12));
        return View(vid);
    }
```

**View**

```
<a href="@item.masterurl/@item.suburl/@item.videoslink" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lstview_ctrl0_A1_0" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="@item.videoImage" alt="The Arctic Light" class="entry-thumb" />
            <div class="video-flag">
            </div>
        </a>
```

**route url for above code **
www.domain.com/category/videos/Amazing-Leak

Comment: Not clear what you question is but is the route defined before the default route? And what does `<a href="@item.masterurl/@item.suburl/@item.videoslink" ..` actually generate for the `href` value?

Comment: /category/videos/Amazing-Leak

Comment: Do you have other more generic routes defined in `RouteConfig.cs` before this one (the order you define the routes is important)

Comment: nothing define in RouteConfing.cs

Answer (score 0):

The framework is trying to find a value passed to it in the request that matches the name of the parameter that you have specified in the action method. Among the places it looks in are the query string, the posted data and route information.

The link you provided has no query string, and there is no posted data, so the only place to look for the parameter is in the route info. The route specifies a "Page" section, the framework uses that to fill the parameter the action method is expecting.

If you change the parameter name to id, the framework can no longer match it to anything and will therefore pass in null to the action method. If you want to use id as the parameter name, change the last section in the route to `{id}` instead of `{page}`. Or you can change the link to include a query string specifying a passed in variable as in: `?id=somevalue`and you can then cancel the `{id}` section of the route. In case you go with the second option, don't forget to URL encode the value before passing it in.

Comment: when i am using parameter name {id} instead of {page} in controller , route was working fine and passing value .